# Wrap :retab! or create a new command that calls it?

Tags: neovim, functions, retab

My vim does most everything what I want with `:retab!` one thing I would like it to do in addition is remove all trailing whitespace like this,

```
:%s/\s\+$//
```

Is there a way to redefine `:retab!` such that the above command runs after it. If not, can I define another function (`:fixws!`) that calls `:retab!` and the above regex?

Comment: @Quasímodo how can I create my own then, like `:fixws!`

Answer (score 2):

I would propose:

```
function! Fixws()
  retab!
  %s/\s\+$//
endfunction

command! Fixws :call Fixws()
```

The command is `:Fixws` because the custom command starts with an uppercase.